# Passing parameters to package.json scripts

Tags: json, node.js, webpack

In package.json, it is possible to define a script like

```
"scripts": 
{
  "build": "webpack"
}
```

which can be invoked through

```
npm run build
```

I am using a webpack.config.js which can process parameters. So my pure webpack command works like this:

```
webpack --env.path="path"
```

How can I pass this parameter when I want to invoke webpack via the npm build script? I.e. Is it possible to pass parameters to package.json scripts?